# Buttons disappearing when changing their background

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, material-design

### **Background**

I just started Android Development and my first project is a calculator.
As I had several problems with the grid and the constrained layout, I settled for a table layout. The next step would be to change the look of the buttons to round buttons -> therefore to change their background.

### Problem

When I leave the buttons without a background, 
[the layout looks fine to me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt4TG.png)
The moment I change the background of the button to the preset of round buttons I found online, the button itself and every button after that in the table, [disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAUvx.png).

I guess the problem is an overlaping layout, but I can´t seem to find a solution.

---

Here is the code for the round button

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="40dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_button" />
</ripple>
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/darkColor"/>
            <!---<size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/> -->
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/primaryColor"/>
            <!---<size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/> -->
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/primaryColor"/>
            <!---<size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/> -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing the look of your buttons is common, especially if you want your button to appear different when clicked. I do it programmatically during run-time.

Lets say you want to change the look of your button when it is clicked.
Let's say the Button is called 'my-Button' as your Button Id:

```
final Button my_button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    my_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // This changes the Button Image.
            my_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_new_button_image);
        }
    });
```

When clicked it will change the image used for the button. :)

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply!
My problem at the moment is not to find the way to change the background of the button, but to prevent the layout from screwing up when doing so. Normally it should look [like on this picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zaa_LNB1Dp4h0BwMv4OPrbZJXHWN9XFB/view?usp=drivesdk) (just bigger) 
But instead the buttons just disappear (like on the pictures of op)